# PbDataWindow right click issue on UFT

Tags: powerbuilder, hp-uft

I am trying to mimic mouse right click on `PbDataWindow` on UFT the following way:

```
  PbWindow("w_mdi_base_frame").PbWindow("w_m_edit_order").PbDataWindow("dw_open_jobsteps").SelectCell "#1","completed_dt"
  Shell.SendKeys "+{F10}"
```

But after I run, I do not see my expected items in the drop-down list, instead, I see in the drop down following items (Undo, Cut, Copy, Paste, Delete, Select All, Right to left Reading order, Show Unicode Control Characters, Insert ....)
I assume these are the standard items for `PbWindow` class object. How can I get `PbDataWindow` drop down items by right clicking? Or how I should implement right click correctly in my UFT script?

Comment: Here Seki suggested a reason of the failure, and a solution which I can not implement:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41660590/how-to-select-specific-element-in-powerbuilder-window-using-hp-uft

Comment: Don't know solution offhand but possibly that datawindow control needs to be "active" for the right button click to relate. You can use accessibility info for automated testing but once you get into datawindow control you cannot rely on the name of object to be consistent from app instance to app instance. Without digging deeper this is all that comes to mind- glad to see someone working on automated testing for PB - so extra motivation to help you. Maybe look at whether datawindow control has FOCUS or ACTIVE which I'd see as being important. Possibly via SetFocus, or BringToFront, etc.

Comment: It should be an option of the `.Click` event to choose which button is used for the click - I'm not familiar with `PbDataWindow` elements but would assume this is an option here?

Comment: Have you tried using ActivateCell instead of SelectCell ? Also PBDataWindow has a click function which can be used like below   PbWindow("w_mdi_base_frame").PbWindow("w_m_edit_order").PbDataWindow("dw_open_jobsteps").Click 10, 10, micRightBtn